# Aligning divs in a row with "display: inline-block" property doesn't align properly

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align divs in a row with `display: inline-block`. It works fine till I put a `<input />` inside the div. Please take a look at the [codepen](https://codepen.io/kumarabinash/pen/pabzVz)

Here is the code for html:

```
<div class="x"></div>

<div class="x">
  <input type="text">
</div>

<div class="x"></div>
```

And for css:

```
.x{
  display: inline-block;
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  background: #eee;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

I already know the solution for aligning them the proper way. I want to understand **why** this is happening in the above case.

Comment: I happens because you left `vertical-align` at its default value `baseline` ... specify `top` instead for the div elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> by default `vertical-align` is `baseline`.

*change it like this:*

```
.x {
    vertical-align: top;
    //other css...
}
```

```css
.x {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  background: #eee;
  margin-right: 10px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="x"></div>

<div class="x">
  <input type="text" />
</div>

<div class="x"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.x{
  display: inline-block;
  height: 250px;
  width: 20%;
  background: #eee;
  margin-right: 10px;
  vertical-align:middle
}
```

```html
<div class="x"></div>

<div class="x">
  <input type="text">
</div>

<div class="x"></div>
```

```
vertcal-align:middle;
```

Add it to align your divs vertically